# Converting Tab-delimited reference list into a bibtex format (using R?)

Tags: bibtex, r, python, mendeley

I need to export search results from Web of Science (i.e. all the results of a query, 100s of entries) and import them in Mendeley with their abstract.
while I usually can export a citation in a .bib format for a single file and import it in mendeley, when trying to export all the search result obtained when searching "All databases" in WOS I do not have the option of exporting in a bibtex format.

Basically, none of the format offered from WOS for export is compatible with Mendeley when searching "All databases".

I am looking for a workaround to solve this problem. In this sense, I thought to export a tab-delimited text file from WOS and then somehow convert it to a bibtex format. I did find a similar solution [here](https://gist.github.com/hpiwowar/1043879) but I do not know Python.

Does anyone knows how to go from a tab-delimited file to a bibtex in R? I found a package "RefManageR" which as a function as.BibEntry that seems to work with data frames but I can't figure out how to correctly use it (I never really used bibtex format, import/export aside)

Does anyone solved this problem in any other way?

Comment: In https://libguides.usask.ca/c.php?g=218034&p=1445132 it looks as though it should be possible to also export multiple results as `.bib` file.

Comment: @moewe unfortunately the solution in the link is not a solution: there you actually have the possibility to export in .bib (and thus import in mendeley no problem). The proble is that when your search is done selecting the option "All databases" you do not have the ".bib" option. At least not always.